# Perl pack and unpack functions

Tags: perl

I am trying to unpack a variable containing a string received from a [spectrum analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer): 
    #42404?û¢-+Ä¢-VÄ¢-oÆ¢-8æ¢-bÉ¢-ôÿ¢-+Ä¢-?Ö¢-sÉ¢-ÜÖ¢-¦ö¢-=Æ¢-8æ¢-uô¢-=Æ¢-\Å¢-uô¢-?ü¢-}¦¢-=Æ¢-)...

The format is real 32 which uses four bytes to store each value. The number #42404 represents 4 extra bytes present and 2404/4 = 601 points collected. The data starts after #42404. Now when I receive this into a string variable,

```
$lp = ibqry($ud,":TRAC:DATA? TRACE1;*WAI;");
```

I am not sure how to convert this into an array of numbers :(... Should I use something like the followin?

```
@dec = unpack("d", $lp);
```

I know this is not working, because I am not getting the right values and the number of data points for sure is not 601...

Comment: What is the "Real 32" format?

Comment: Number representation...

Comment: Real 32 sounds like Fortran REAL*4, a 32-bit floating point number, aka C `float`.  That means you have a string containing type and count information, followed by the relevant number of bytes of data.  Do you know if the data in the string is presented in the native byte order or in some other order?  This will radically affect the answer.

Comment: Normal mode is when the byte sequence begins with the most significant byte (MSB) first, and ends with the least significant byte (LSB) last in the sequence: I can also swap it on the instrument using command to Swapped mode is when the byte sequence begins with the LSB first, and
ends with the MSB last in the sequence

Comment: @user2829 It might be useful to post a hex dump of the value.  Then we can see what the data is.  The character transliteration isn't helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to strip the `#42404` off and hope none of the following binary data happens to be an ASCII number.

```
$lp =~ s{^#\d+}{};
```

I'm not sure what format "Real 32" is, but I'm going to guess that it's a single precision floating point which is 32 bits long.  Looking at [the pack docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). `d` is "double precision float", that's 64 bits.  So I'd try `f` which is "single precision".

```
@dec = unpack("f*", $lp);
```

Whether your data is [big or little endian](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Endian) is a problem.  `d` and `f` use your computer's native endianness.  You may have to force endianness using the `>` and `<` modifiers.

```
@dec = unpack("f*>", $lp);  # big endian
@dec = unpack("f*<", $lp);  # little endian
```

Comment: so do i need to use pack something like this my $lp = pack ("f"). and can i specify the exact number of bytes to read ?

Comment: also I get only one element in the array :(       -77.7630004882813

Comment: You are unpacking binary data into Perl data.  You can specify the number of times to repeat the format, *not the number of bytes*.  See "Each letter may optionally be followed by a number indicating the repeat count..." in the pack docs.  In your example you would use `unpack("f[601]", $lp)` to unpack 601 floating point numbers from $lp.

Comment: @user2829 My mistake, I forgot the `*` on the pack format indicating it should unpack more than one number.  You can use `*` or the exact count given to you in the `#12345` header.

Comment: ...and, more generally, you'd read the 2404 (or whatever the value is) and divide by 4 and then arrange for your pack format to read that many floats.

Comment: thank you so much for the replies.. :) I appreciate it. For some reason I still read only 62 values. When i do print $#dec it prints 61. But i guess if i am collecting 601 points :(...

Comment: @user2829 Maybe `$lp` doesn't contain all the data.  Is `length($lp)` anything like 2404?

Answer (score 1):

If the first `4` encodes the number of remaining digits (`2404`) before the floats, then something like this might work:

```perl
my @dec = unpack "x a/x f>*", $lp;
```

The `x` skips the leading `#`, the `a/x` reads one digit and skips that many characters after it, and the `f>*` parses the remaining string as a sequence of 32-bit big-endian floats.  (If the output looks weird, try using `f<*` instead.)

Comment: thank you so much for the replies.. :) I appreciate it. For some reason I still read only 62 values. When i do print $#dec it prints 61. But i guess if i am collecting 601 points :(...

Comment: @user2829: How long is `$lp`?  If it's not 2 + 4 + 2404 = 2410 characters, then something is wrong.

Comment: @limari :- I am using Perl so I guess I don't need to specify the length of the Variable or Do I ??? If so how?

Comment: @user2829: No, you don't need to specify the length; all Perl strings know their length, which you can find out using (surprise!) [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html).